# Is multiple inheritance a good design pattern in my case?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I have the following problem:
I want to have multiple Windows all displaying some kind of function graphs. Say one window should show a Coordinate Axis and have some interaction features, another window should also display a coordinate axis and have a settings dialog.

How I intuitively would go about this, is to implement `Window` as some class which does the initialization of the basic window with my framework (in my case VTK), some virtual inherited classes `WindowWithAxis`, `WindowInteracting`, `WindowWithSettingsDialog` and then have

- class `A` inherit `WindowInteracting` and `WindowCoordinateAxis`
- class `B` inherit `WindowWithSettingsDialog` and `WindowCoordinateAxis`

So reading through the internet I now saw everywhere (for example the Google Style Guide), that I only should do this if `Window`, `WindowInteracting`, `WindowCoordinateAxis`, `WindowWithSettingsDialog` are all pure abstract classes/interfaces.

And this is what I don't understand. Doesn't this mean that I am not allowed to actually implement these classes and that I will have to implement all the functionality of `Window` and of `WindowCoordinateAxis`in class `A` and class `B` (and every other class which uses these)? That seems not like a clean solution to me.

This kind of "Diamond shaped Inheritance" should be a problem that occurs quite often, so what are the ways in which I can approach this?

Comment: This would be more appropriate in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I wouldnt use a window as base class for a window with coordinate axis, but rather use composition. As soon as you want to have 2 coordinate axis in the same windows it will get complicated by your design (while in priciple it should be easy)

Comment: IMO it will not stay with just `WindowWithAxis`, `WindowInteracting` and `WindowWithSettingsDialog`. You will soon have `WindowWithButton`, `WindowWith2Axis`, `WindowWithScrollbar` and your classes will be an unchangeable mess of code because everything is related to everything and it is impossible to do anything without a full redesign. Stick to just `Window` and make an `Axis` which is a `Window` and make it so you can add `Window`s to other `Window`s. Or just use Qt with QWT which already solved all of this for you.

Comment: @Rosme when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: The very reason people warn against multiple inheritance is because this method of cobbling together a do-it-all object by inheriting from everything that it needs to do if very hard to maintain and makes reusing code harder in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The general principle is avoiding code/functionality repetitions and promoting reusability. In your case, `WindowInteracting` and `WindowCoordinateAxis` classes both have the same functionality(comes from being a Window). Instead, either, define an interface(class with pure virtual functions) named `IInteracting` and `IHasTheCoordinateAxis` and provide a concrete realization of them, or, make your `Window` class behave different according to passed parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd approach the following way:

Define a polymorphic Window base class which is the interface through which UI events are handled.

Derive a WindowImpl from that, which is templated with a list of Feature classes. Each feature can choose whether or not to respond to an event.

The WindowImpl calls the code for the event on each Feature object by enumerating a tuple of features. Features may maintain their own state.

e.g.:

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

/// Basic concept of a window that handles events
struct Window
{
    Window(std::string title)
        : title_(std::move(title)) {}

    // all windows handle clicks, but defer to a private polymorphic implementation
    void onClickOrWhatever()
    {
        handleOnClickOrWhatever();
    }

    // all windows have a title
    auto title() const -> const std::string&
    {
        return title_;
    }

private:
    // make ploymorphism an implementation detail
    virtual void handleOnClickOrWhatever() = 0;

    std::string title_;
};

// All concrete windows are a WindowImpl customised with a feature list
template<class...Features>
struct WindowImpl
    : Window
{
    static constexpr auto FeatureCount = sizeof...(Features);

    using Window::Window;

private:

    // the onClick handler defers to actions specified by each enabled feature
    void handleOnClickOrWhatever() override
    {
        std::cout << title() << " detects a click (or whatever)\n";
        implHandleOnClickOrWhatever(features_,
                                    std::make_index_sequence<FeatureCount>());
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    template<class FeatureTuple, std::size_t...Is>
    void implHandleOnClickOrWhatever(FeatureTuple&& features, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        using expand = int[];
        void(expand{0,
                    (std::get<Is>(features).handleClick(*this), 0)...
        });

    }


    using FeatureTuple = std::tuple<Features...>;
    FeatureTuple features_;
};



// a base feature that takes no action
struct BaseFeature
{
    template<class Window>
    static void handleClick(Window& window)
    {
        // don't respond
    }
};

//
// some features
//

struct HasAxis
    : BaseFeature
{
    template<class Window>
    static void handleClick(Window& window)
    {
        std::cout << "testing touch on axis" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct HasSettingsDialog
    : BaseFeature
{
    template<class Window>
    static void handleClick(Window& window)
    {
        std::cout << "testing touch on settings button" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct HasAlphaBackground
    : BaseFeature
{
    // note : does not handle clicks
};

// some customised windows, mixing anf matching features
using WindowWithAxis = WindowImpl<HasAxis>;
using WindowWithAxisAndSettings = WindowImpl<HasAxis, HasSettingsDialog>;
using WindowWithAxisAndAlpha = WindowImpl<HasAxis, HasAlphaBackground>;

int main()
{
    WindowWithAxis w{"window 1"};
    w.onClickOrWhatever();

    WindowWithAxisAndSettings w2{"window 2"};
    w2.onClickOrWhatever();

    WindowWithAxisAndAlpha w3{"window 3"};
    w3.onClickOrWhatever();
}
```

expected output:

```
window 1 detects a click (or whatever)
testing touch on axis

window 2 detects a click (or whatever)
testing touch on axis
testing touch on settings button

window 3 detects a click (or whatever)
testing touch on axis
```